# Image exceeds parent (child div exceeds parent div)

Tags: html, css

I have read all answers I think to this SO question, and changed `max-height` to every different combination, but it still bothers me;

I have the following

```html
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="products-container">

    {% for p in current_lists %}

    <div class="item">

      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="{{p.image_url}}" alt="Image of product added" />
      </div>

      <div class="total-price">{{price}}

      </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>

</div>
```

and CSS

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.products-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

.products-container .item{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The issue is, that the image expands outside the blue-box
[image]

[image]

I have tried changing `max-height` in `img` and in `products-container .item` down to 10%, but it does not scale the big image at all.

Comment: Have you tried `height` and `width` instead of `max-height` etc?

Comment: Also, I tried your code using `px`  instead of `%` in the container `height` and `width` and it worked. Since `%` is relative, it may be the problem.

Comment: Try `img {height: 100%; width: auto}`

Comment: Why would setting `height` work when `max-height` is set, and it's the height that's exceeding? Am I misunderstanding those two properties?

Answer (score 1):

If height is the issue then I would say:

width:100%;
height:auto;

I added your bits into a codepen and didn't have the issue:
https://codepen.io/liam88/pen/zYwYNVN

```
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="products-container">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/600x600" alt="Image of product added"/>
 </div>
   <div class="total-price">£12.99</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/600x600" alt="Image of product added"/>
 </div>
   <div class="total-price">£12.99</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/daily" alt="Image of product added"/>
 </div>
   <div class="total-price">£12.99</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.products-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

.products-container .item{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I think OP may be trying to keep the blue-box from expanding

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution:

Setting the container `height` to auto, and manipulating the `width`. I also used align-self: flex-end to make sure everything is aligned to the bottom of the blue-box. Using proportional images will make it all of them the same height, after auto-resizing.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.products-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

.products-container .item{
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    align-self: flex-end;
}

.image-wrapper img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="products-container">



    <div class="item">

      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://cdn-images.farfetch-contents.com/14/66/46/09/14664609_23855407_1000.jpg" alt="Image of product added" />
      </div>

      <div class="total-price">{{price}}

      </div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="item">

      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41DIxdHUYCL._AC_UL1020_.jpg" alt="Image of product added" />
      </div>

      <div class="total-price">{{price}}

      </div>
    </div>
            <div class="item">

      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://assets.burberry.com/is/image/Burberryltd/2d6345e1d1fe0353ef7f95098c4d890c0a76ebb1.jpg?$BBY_V2_SL_1x1$&wid=2800&hei=2800" alt="Image of product added" />
      </div>

      <div class="total-price">{{price}}

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How come, I cannot manipulate the `height` directly? I thought setting `max-height` restricted the child div relatively to the parent div?